# After I trigger a jqmodal and close it ,my website get a Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jqmodal

My website is runnable(include a onclick slidetoggle,masonry ....)

before i trigger a jqmodal,

but when i trigger a jqmodal and close it,

my website is get a  "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry'"

I think i need to add a reload 
when the jqmodal close.

but  i  don't know how to do in js

Any  idea? Or the other possible errors ?

my sources code------

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
     <script>

              $("#Item-search-bar").click(function(){
                $("#Item-search-list").slideToggle(500,function(){
                    $('#container').masonry();
here got error-->"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry' "
                });
             });

  </script>
```

Comment: Check the value of `$('#container')` in console

Comment: sorry ,i have no idea to check what kind of value ...:(
i use chrome's console, and it just tell me "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry' (anonymous function)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means the `masonry` plugin was not loaded. Most likely the `jquery.masonry.min.js` file is missing or has a different filename.

In the browser if you View -> Source, you can click the link to the Javascript file to see if it exists or not.

Comment: It's exist! I click the link and can view the masonry.min.js!
but still can't work...

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem?